# Why they are considering as seven months ? (Actuarial problem)

Tags: probability

Question : A company takes out an insurance policy to cover accidents that occur at its manufacturing plant. The probability that one or more accidents will occur during any given month is 0.60. The numbers of accidents that occur in different months are mutually independent.
Calculate the probability that there will be at least four months in which no accidents occur before the fourth month in which at least one accident occurs.

Answer : One way to view this event is that in the first seven months there must be at least four with no accidents. These are binomial probabilities:
$\sum_{k=1}^{7}$$ 7 \choose k$$(0.4)^4(0.6)^{(7-k)}$
or considering as Negative binomial probabilities : $\sum_{k=0}^{3}$$k+4-1 \choose k$$(0.4)^4$$0.6^k$.

My question that I try to figure out that why they are considering first seven months, because I think if there were sequences like n,n,n,a,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,a where n is no accident and a is an accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event of interest is

> There will be at least four months in which no accidents occur before the fourth month in which at least one accident occurs.

If we regard a month with no accidents as a success, and a month with at least one accident as a failure, then the event is equivalent to:

> There are at least four successes before the fourth failure.

The complementary event is

> There are **at most three** successes before the fourth failure.

So this is why you know if you have seen the desired event by the seventh month, because exactly one of these things happens by the end of the seventh month:

1. You saw three or fewer successes before you saw the fourth failure.
2. You saw four or more successes and you have not yet seen the fourth failure.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping , it was clear for me.

Comment: @SiWarak if my answer is helpful, feel free to accept and/or upvote it.